# Use value from select in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to build query that will use parameter from query in subquery such as:

```
SELECT
    A.Name,
    CASE (SELECT SUM(A.Time) FROM A WHERE A.Name = A.Name)
FROM A
```

How can I do something like this. Thing needed mentioning is that the query will return multiple rows and for each of them I want to take sum based on the name from query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery here, use a windowed `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT A.[Name]
       CASE SUM(A.[Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY A.[Name]) WHEN ... END AS Something --HOw do you SUM a "time"???
FROM A;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function for such requirements but if you want to know how to use subquery in `select` clause then you can use the `alias` as follows:

```
SELECT
    A.Name,
    (SELECT SUM(A.Time) FROM A WHERE t.Name = A.Name) 
FROM A t -- t is the alias
```